# Como fazer um scroll em seções uma página HTML com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Olá! Como posso fazer um Fullpage mousewheel (navegar em `<section>` ou `<div>`) em uma página HTML com JavaScript?

Comment: Acho que entendi a duvida, você quer é uma espécie de slide vertical, acho que o nome disto é *Fullpage mousewheel*. Vou editar a pergunta, qualquer coisa faça o rollback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peguei carona [nesta resposta do SOzão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25839854/916193), que já tinha o código pronto.

O exemplo é em jQuery, mas dá pra fazer numa boa com JavaScript puro (aliás, é o recomendável, a não ser que seu site já seja todo baseado em jQuery).

O importante é entender dois conceitos:

1. `on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll')`

   O `mousewheel` é disparado quando a roda do mouse é acionada; o `DOMMouseScroll` é o equivalente do Firefox para isto.
2. `event.preventDefault();`

   Como você vai gerenciar o evento da roda do mouse, é fundamental que você avise o navegador que não é para usar a ação normal para aquele evento. Aí que entra o `preventDefault`.

### Demonstração

Clique em "Executar trecho de código" logo abaixo do bloco a seguir, clique no *frame* e teste com a roda do mouse.

```js
(function() {
  var delay = false;

  $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(delay) return;

    delay = true;
    setTimeout(function(){delay = false},200)

    var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

    var a= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    if(wd < 0) {
      for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
        var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
        if(t >= 40) break;
      }
    }
    else {
      for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
        if(t < -20) break;
      }
    }
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
body, html { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0 }
a { display:block; color:red; margin-bottom:1em; }
.page {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0 auto;padding:0 15%;box-sizing:border-box;background:#fee}
.page:nth-child(odd) {background:#efe}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <a name="#A1">Tag #1</a>
  <b>TESTE TAMBEM EM PAGINA TODA -----------></b><br>
  At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.
</div>
<div class="page">
  <a name="#A2">Tag #2</a>
  At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus.
</div>
<div class="page">
  <a name="#A3">Tag #3</a>
  At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus.
</div>
<div class="page">
  <a name="#A4">Tag #4</a>
  At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus.
</div>
```

Comment: Bacco, aconselhe também que coloque em "Página toda". A experiência fica deveras melhor e se assemelha ao site. +1

Comment: @SamirBraga Acrescentei no html :)